# Как запустить ВК бота на heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, бот

Всем привет, никак не могу запустить бота на хероку. 
В проекте: bot.py, chromedriver.exe (для селениума), Procfile, в нем одна строка: 'bot: python3 namebot.py' (возможно в этом проблема). runtime.txt: 'python-3.7.4' и requirements.txt. Сам бот работает через callback api, обрабатывает запросы с помощью flask. Раньше хостил на pythonEW, но он не поддерживает chromedriver, пришлось перенести.

Я задеплоил его на heroku, но он не работает и я не понимаю как его запустить, перечитал какие только есть мануалы и ничего не получается. Пробовал ставить web: bot.py в Procfile и heroku ps:scale web=1, но все равно ничего не работало. Сейчас стоит heroku ps:scale bot=1. И я не понимаю до конца что именно надо ставить, потому что в половине мануалов по ботам стоит web, в другой половине bot..

heroku logs:

```
2019-11-23T17:06:29.862867+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 0efbd699 by user                         
name@gmail.com
2019-11-23T17:06:44.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2019-11-23T17:17:00.242056+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No     
web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=vk-ghetto-bot.herokuapp.com         
request_id=91f4486a-75eb-44a7-9cfa-bd61aa3897c5 fwd="5.44.169.xxx" dyno=     
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-11-23T17:17:00.555695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No 
web processes running" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=name- 
bot.herokuapp.com request_id=b7b7440d-5249-4278-a3b7-b09681f1fdd6 
fwd="5.44.169.xxx" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

upd: поменял на heroku ps:scale bot=1

теперь логи:

```
2019-11-23T18:03:00.587059+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App     
crashed" method=GET path="/" host=name.herokuapp.com         
request_id=610cdcc7-25d3-465f-9139-c16299d81a68 fwd="5.44.169.xxx" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-11-23T18:03:00.880446+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App 
crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=name.herokuapp.com 
request_id=1ace8a4c-8fca-4824-8567-f71f779cd1c9 fwd="5.44.169.xxx" dyno= 
connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Возможно что-то не так с этой строчкой, но я пока не понимаю почему.

```
python
@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def main():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    if data["type"] == "confirmation":
    return "confirmation code"
```

Answer (score 1):

Спустя 7 часов гуглений и попыток решил свою проблему!

Ещё утром я не знал, как работает git, heroku и flask, а теперь понимаю хотя бы основы.

Что бы пофиксить ошибку понадобилось:

1) Поменять heroku ps:scale bot=1 на heroku ps:scale web=1
2) В Procfile поменять bot: python3 namebot.py на web: python namebot.py
3) В самой программе добавить:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
app.debug = True
app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))
```

И все заработало)

Comment: неплохо было бы написать почему именно так